# Better alternatives to regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem, where I need to match the model name of a product from it's string title. I also have a database containing known models, and I am only intending to **match and replace** those known models.

At the moment, I am using a regular expression for this, in the following manner:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|,|;|\s)(WinterContact\sTs830|WinterContact\sContiWinter|....|Blizzak\sL360)(?=$|,|;|\s)/', $string, ...);
```

For the sake of speed, at the moment this seems sufficient to me, however the database with the models is rather small at the moment (~2000 model names). In the future, this database will most likely grow, and it can easily be MUCH MUCH larger, and this leads to a problem for me: **the length of the regular expression string.**

In php, with previous tests I've found out, that there is a maximum length of the string that you can input as the pattern for the regular expression. So basically, if I exceed this length, I will, instead of performing one regular expression operation, need to perform multiple operations, based on the the size of my model database.

A possible alternative to the regular expression would be the `str_replace` function, but for one, I don't think I can do the positive lookahead and lookbehind with it, and I presume it will be MUCH slower then the regular expression itself.

Are there any alternatives to resolve this problem in PHP, besides these two(?) options? Namely to **match and replace known models from a database in multiple input strings**?

Comment: I'd standardize the title format, if possible, such that the model name part of the title is its own string, then use an array or associative array to check if the model name in a given title is one of the ones to be replaced, removing the regex logic entirely.

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you elaborate on this please? How do you mean standardize the title format? I don't know at the beginning if the title string even CONTAINS a model name, and I don't know which model it contains, if it contains one. The titles are basically product names from webshops different product feeds.

Comment: The PCRE VM usually outperforms whatever you concoct in PHP with string functions. What your regex lacks is likely just the `/x` flag and `model(\d+)` instead of the list. Avoiding loops, proper database indexes and profiling are more important when it really comes to performance problems. (I doubt that single regex would make a blip.)

Comment: @mario the `model(\d+)` would not help me, as models in my database not always contain numbers, and when they do, they are not standardized at all. a real life example from my database for two separate tire models are: `ContiWinterContact TS860 RS` and `ContiWinterContact TS830`. I need to match both of these models, replace them, and I then need to store the matched model in a standardized format besides the title.

Comment: @mario Oh, I see why you came with that suggestion. My regex example in the question is just to signify that a list all the possible model names in a capture group separated with pipes. Those or not the actual model names I am looking for, they not all have the structure of the string model and a number. I have updated the question.

Comment: Alright. If they're also containing spacing and whatnot, then I'd also suggest a change in the database design. Use a separate column for the models and some templating scheme (e.g. title = "xyz%model%-xyz"). Though that might just be shifting your presumed performance woe from the search function(?) to the presentation/output logic. // Or is this question about resolving an URL slug or similar?

Comment: Right now my database table is of the following structure: `ModelId|ModelName|Aliases` where the `ModelId` is an autoincremented id for each model, the `ModelName` contains a normalized name of the model, it is unique, and the `Aliases` contain `|` separated aliases which should normalize to this specific model. This database is not populated by a programmer, basically, one of our admins, can add a plain text alias for a known model name, or create a new model name when needed and alias it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index field (contains everything you need to select) in your database to avoid intensive tasks on your web server (he should only serve the web)
in this case, the web server build a native select query, and then the database engine handles the rest of it.

```
Select * from T1 where (index like "exp_1") OR .. (index like "exp_N");
```

but we do not forget that we must now manage redendance in the DB if you will use index filed.